# With Service account, Not getting any files / folder list with PHP

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth, service-accounts

What will extra setting to get files / folder from google drive API with service account? Currently getting empty results.

Same code working with credential web scope with client id and secrets key but not with service account.

Comment: Do you want to list the files in your account (other user account) with the services account?

Comment: We will use just single account with our company domain. All files and folders will be share to that account.

Comment: Have you tried impersonating the user with the services account using ["delegate domain-wide authority"](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests)? That might help, you can impersonate the user that will have access to all the files and folders.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code [example]  or at very least tell me what programming language you are using so i can show you some code.

Comment: @GiselleValladares google drive doesn't require delegation. You can do it without it.

Comment: @DalmTo, Yes, it is not necessary if they share the files and folders with the service accounts, or when the files are owned by the services account. 

However, if they want to skip the step to share the file with the service account, then they can use delegation. I recommended using delegation since the OP mentioned they are handling files from the domain, and it should be feasible for them because they seem to be using Google Workspace.

Comment: The question does not mention workspace if they are using workspace the question needs to be edited to state that

Comment: I am using PHP google client api. https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client

Comment: Are you using a Google Workspace account?

Comment: If you are then, you can use: `$client->setSubject($user_to_impersonate);` to impersonate the user in your domain that has all the files shared with it. You can read more information [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#authentication-with-service-accounts)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use a web client. It pops up and requests authorizaiton.  In this way a user is granting your application access to their data.  So a file.list will return the files on the users google drive account.

The same thing is happening with your service account. Only service accounts are pre authorized.  Your file.list is returning no files becouse the service account doesnt have acess to any files yet.  You see it has its own drive account.

Options.

1. Upload files to the service accounts drive account.
2. open your credetials.json file. Look for the service account email address. Take that address and share a directory or file on your personal drive account with the service account.

Now do a file.list.  It should have files.

Comment: I did same. Authorization working but getting empty files result with service account.

Comment: i have created web authorization client with same service account, and getting file lists. just did extra step to generate access token which expire in just one hour.

Comment: Your confusing things.   You cant use web client code with service account code. They are two different things.  Please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: Watch this even if your not using node. It will give you an idea of what you need to fix [Google drive API upload file with Nodejs + service account](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z2MCxblgPoc)

Comment: I am using php google api client to get files and folders.

Comment: I can find you a sample for php google drive and a service account in the morning.